# How to run Spring Shell scripts in a JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-shell

I have a [Spring Shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell)-based application and a couple of scripts. Is there an easy way to run the scripts in a JUnit test such that a test fails, if some exception/error occurs during the execution of the script?

The purpose of the tests is to make sure that all correct scripts run without errors.

**Update 1:**

Here's a little helper class for running scripts in JUnit:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap;
import org.springframework.shell.core.CommandResult;
import org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShellComponent;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.*;

public class ScriptRunner {
  public void runScript(final File file) throws IOException 
  {
    final Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    final JLineShellComponent shell = bootstrap.getJLineShellComponent();

    final List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
    for (final String line : lines) {
      execVerify(line, shell);
    }   
  }
  private void execVerify(final String command, final JLineShellComponent shell) {
    final CommandResult result = shell.executeCommand(command);
    assertThat(result.isSuccess()).isTrue();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of `Bootstrap`, get the `shell` out of it and then `executeCommand()` (including the `shell` command) on it.

You may be interested in what is done in Spring XD for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-shell/src/test/java/org/springframework/xd/shell/AbstractShellIntegrationTest.java (although there are a lot of XD specific details)